# Copy worksheet to last sheet with same name?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet named "Book 1". I have no problem copy to after that worksheet. My issue is the next copy, I will already have "Book 1" then "Book 1 (2)" I need to copy the "Book 1" but place it after "Book 1(2)" and so forth with the next copy. How can I keep track or know where to place the next copy? I Don't want to put it at the end either because there are other tabs at the end that needs to be there.

```
Sub CopySheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If Left(ws.Name, 4) = "Book" Then
    Sheets("Book 1").Copy After:=Sheets(ws.Name)
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest coming up with a better naming convention because as written the code will copy each worksheet whose names begins with `Book`. So first time it will copy `Book 1` and create `Book 1 (2)`. Then second time it will copy `Book 1` as `Book 1 (3)` and `Book 1 (2)` as `Book 1 (2) (2)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want Book 1 (2), Book 1(3), Book 1(4).......same worksheet, it's like adding worksheet with the same name but I need it to go after the one previous created because i have a few worksheets at the end of the workbook that i want to keep it there.

Comment: You're modifying the collection you're iterating. Make an array or collection with the sheet names you want to copy, and iterate that instead.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, can you put that in an answer? I'm not entirely sure what you mean?

Comment: @CallumDA I would, but I'm not sure what the loop actually intends to be doing, so I'd rather not. Doesn't make sense to me that it's copying the same sheet over and over. Looks like that conditional is making an assumption that there's only 1 sheet whose name starts with "Book"? In that case I don't understand what the loop is needed for. Maybe I'm dumb, but I don't think OP's code *does what it says* and *says what it does*.

Comment: @pokemon_Man - if you can clarify what Mat's Mug is referring too in above comment, we can probably help you get the exact code you need. As is, there are many uncertainties based on what you have provided.

Comment: Basically, I need to copy "Book 1" and put it after the latest "Book 1" tab as in the picture it would be "Book 1 (3)"

Comment: @pokemon_Man - so everytime you run the code you want to only copy `Book 1` behind the last copy of `Book 1`?

Comment: yes. so if the last one is "Book 1 (3)" i want to copy "Book 1" to after that one.

Comment: @pokemon_Man - what if the sheets end up out of order? Like if Book 1 (4) is moved between Book 1 (2) and Book 1 (3)? Or that will never happen?

Comment: it will never happen, it will always stay in order and i want it to stay in order.

Comment: @pokemon_Man - see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tested code. Worked for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheet()

    'copy Book 1 sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Book 1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

    'assign to variable to move later
    Dim wsPlacement As Worksheet
    Set wsPlacement = ActiveSheet

    'load all "Book 1" sheets
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets

        If Left(ws.Name, 6) = "Book 1" And ws.Name <> wsPlacement.Name Then

            Dim sSheets As String
            sSheets = sSheets & "," & ws.Name

        End If

    Next ws

    'find last one (by index) and move copy after that one
    'this works so long as sheets stay in numerical order of copy
         'if not it will put sheet at last position (by index) of Book 1 sheets
    sSheets = Mid(sSheets, 2) 'remove leading comma
    Dim arrSheets() As String
    arrSheets = Split(sSheets, ",")

    wsPlacement.Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(arrSheets(UBound(arrSheets)))


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop backwards thru all sheets and copy it after the last where the name matches.

```
Sub copyMe(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ws.Parent
    For i = wb.Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        If ws.Name = Left(wb.Sheets(i).Name, Len(ws.Name)) Then
            ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: can you modified answer to not use worksheet as a argument and take "Book 1" as the sheet?

Comment: Why do you want it without parameters? Let the sub do what it is supposed to do (copy a sheet) and the calling routine tell for what is should do the work. Just call it like `copyMe activeworkbook.sheets("Book 1")` or whatever sheet you want to copy.